# How to animate a human face mesh using shape keys?

Tags: python, key, shapes, blender, mesh

I have a simple mesh in the shape of the a human face, that I need to animate in terms of various facial expressions given the coordinate positions of the different facial features (like inner outer corners of eyes, lips, eyebrows etc) for different frames (>500) as text files.

I'm fairly new to blender and python but from a little research it was obvious that the answer lies in using shape keys, but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Just a note, the [StackExchange site for 3D graphics and modeling](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics-modeling-applications) has reached it's commitment and should go into private beta soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking for a way to do [this](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3aManual/Animation/Techs/Shape/Shape_Keys), but programatically?

Here's a tutorial on [scripting them](http://www.packtpub.com/article/blender-2.49-scripting-shape-keys-ipo-and-poses). I have't scripted with Blender in a *long* time, but the documentation is out there (somewhere).

If you must, just run the `help()` function on modules and functions. They are somewhat documented internally.

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what the code needs to perform! Thanks a lot for the link, but would you happen to know a similar scripting sample for 2.5x?

Comment: The API shouldn't have changed much. I don't use 2.5, sadly, so I wouldn't know any specifics, but you can play around with it. Just see what errors you get.

Comment: All right, I was stumbling upon way too much helpful material in 2.4 version, so I'm just reverting to that now, i'll report my progress, thanks :)

Comment: As much as I love 2.5, I still like 2.4 way more. It's just more stable and faster to work with. I'll see what I can dig up on the API changes, though.

Comment: I'm exploring the 2.4 UI right now, I could get used to this, Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. Check the source code and you will get with the solution. The key is to use shape keys.
https://www.stickmanventures.com/labs/demo/webgl-threejs-morph-target/#